# Homebrew requires something uninstall-developer-folder removes

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

I was having trouble installing irssi (`brew install irssi`), so I ran `brew doctor`, which returned a warning mentioning an outdated copy of Xcode and saying I should run `/Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder`. Then I ran `brew doctor` again and got:

```
Error: No such file or directory - /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
```

How do I reinstall the SDK, or is there another way to get Homebrew working again?

(I have the latest version of Homebrew (0.9.3), the latest version of Xcode (4.4.1), and the latest version of the Xcode CLT (though I'm not sure how to find this version number).)

**UPDATE:** `/Developer` actually still exists (despite the obvious implication of `uninstall-developer-folder`), as does `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk`. Why does Homebrew specifically need Snow Leopard's SDK?

Comment: Do you have a current `brew`, a current Xcode, and current Xcode command-line tools?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. Updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer for Xcode 4.3 should have removed `/Developer/`. I guess `brew doctor` just checks if it exists. I was able to install irssi without it.

Newer versions of the SDKs should be in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/`.

You could probably just delete `/Developer/` completely. See [Uninstall Xcode 4 when it was installed via the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344226/uninstall-xcode-4-when-it-was-installed-via-the-app-store) and [How to remove previous versions of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683858/how-to-remove-previous-versions-of-xcode).